# pausing a thread that is waiting for input?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdin, condition-variable

I'm writing a chess engine , and this is an example of how I want to implement the [UCI protocol](http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html):

```
//search.h
#pragma once
#include<atomic>
static std::atomic_bool stop=false;
namespace Search
{
int Alphabeta()
{
    int r = 10;
    int Rounds = 0;
    while ((++Rounds<20)&&!stop)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
            sum += i;
    }

        sync_cout << sum<< sync_endl;

    }
    sync_cout << "Stopping" << sync_endl;
    return r;
}
```

}

```
//UCI.h
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <sstream>
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>
#include<condition_variable>

enum SyncCout { IO_LOCK, IO_UNLOCK };
//taken from StockFish
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, SyncCout sc) {

static std::mutex m;

if (sc == IO_LOCK) m.lock();

if (sc == IO_UNLOCK) m.unlock();

return os;
}
#define sync_cout std::cout << IO_LOCK
#define sync_endl std::endl << IO_UNLOCK

#include"search.h"

class Thread
{
public:
Thread()
{
    nativeThread = std::thread(&Thread::MainLoop, this);
    sync_cout << "@Constructor" << sync_endl;
}

void MainLoop()
{
    while (!exit)
    {
        while (pause)
        {
            sync_cout << "@Waiting" << sync_endl;
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex);
            cv.wait(lk);
            lk.unlock();
        }
                    sync_cout << "@UCILoop" << sync_endl;

        std::string token, cmd;
        while (!pause && !exit && std::getline(std::cin, cmd))
        {
            sync_cout << "@Processing" << sync_endl;
            std::istringstream is(cmd);
            is >> std::skipws >> token;
            if (token == "stop")
            {
                stop = true;
                PauseThread();
            }
            else if (token == "isready") std::cout << "readyok" << std::endl;
            else if (token == "pause") PauseThread();
        }
    }

}

void PauseThread()
{
    //pause
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mutex);
    pause = true;
}

void ResumeThread()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mutex);
    pause = false;
    cv.notify_one();
}

~Thread()
{
    sync_cout << "@Destructor" << sync_endl;
    mutex.lock();
    pause = false;
    exit = true;
    cv.notify_one();
    mutex.unlock();
    nativeThread.join();
}




private:
std::thread nativeThread;
std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool pause = true, exit = false;
};

namespace UCI
{
void Loop()
{
    Thread th;
            std::cout << "@PrimaryLoop : "<<std::endl;
    std::string token, cmd;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, cmd))
    {
        std::cout << "Processing : ";
        std::istringstream is(cmd);
        is >> std::skipws >> token;
        if (token == "go")
        {
            std::cout << "go ok" << std::endl;
            stop = false;

            th.ResumeThread();
            Search::Alphabeta();
            th.PauseThread();
        }
        else if (token == "isready") std::cout << "readyok" << std::endl;
        else if (token == "quiet")
        {
            std::cout << "quieting" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

and main :

```
#include"UCI.h"
int main()
{
UCI::Loop();
}
```

Everything works ok with the only exception being the case when the search finishes normally without receiving the UCI command "stop" , so the search will return while the secondary UCI thread is waiting for input @"std::getline" , I intended to write to the stdin stream "pause" as can be seen from the code before knowing that this is at the very best non portable & wrong , what are my options or is there another way to pause a thread regardless of what it's currently executing ?

Comment: You need to guard all accesses to `pause` (including `while` condition etc.) with a mutex or make it `std::atomic`.